# VBA gives me the result all on the first sheet, instead of the relevant sheets?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm so close to accomplishing what I set out to do. I basically just need every sum of the columns in all the sheets of my workbook directly at the end of the column. My problem is that the answers all appear on the first sheet instead of the relevant sheets. I can't figure out what I need to change!

Here's what I'm working with

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long, Lastcol As Long

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Lastrow = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    Lastcol = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    Range(Cells(Lastrow, "D"), Cells(Lastrow, Lastcol)).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R1C:R" & Lastrow - 1 & "C)"

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: I need the sum of every column at the end of every column, for every sheet of the workbook. Sorry if I phrased it badly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long, Lastcol As Long

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Lastrow = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    Lastcol = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    ws.Activate

    Range(Cells(Lastrow, "D"), Cells(Lastrow, Lastcol)).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R1C:R" & Lastrow - 1 & "C)"

Next ws

End Sub
```

or (to complete @John Coleman's answer)

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Lastrow As Long, Lastcol As Long

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

        Lastrow = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
        Lastcol = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

        ws.Range(ws.Cells(Lastrow, "A"), ws.Cells(Lastrow, Lastcol)).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R1C:R" & Lastrow - 1 & "C)"

    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: That works as well -- but it is borderline possible that it might trigger some event handlers that you don't want triggered and could also force the user to tab back to the sheet they want if you don't restore it at the end.

Comment: This second part worked well for me! Thank you both so much!

Answer (score 3):

Replace `Range(Cells(Lastrow, "D"), ...` by

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(Lastrow, "D"), ...
```

Since you didn't specify the sheet, `Range` was interpreted in the active sheet.

Comment: `Cells` is also an implicit reference to the `ActiveSheet`... but yeah.

Comment: That stopped the macro from entering the following sheets' totals onto the first sheet, but it only found the sum for the first sheet and not the rest. Any suggestions?